# How to bind the values in html page using angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting the following error with my code while binging:
**Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'standard' of undefined or null reference**
below is my code:
student.component.ts:

```
 this._studentService.get(Global.BASE_USER_ENDPOINT + '/StudentDetailsApi?user_id=' + StudID)
                .do(data => JSON.stringify(data))
                .subscribe(students=> { this.students= students; this.indLoading = false; },
                error => this.msg = <any>error);
```

And student.component.html:

```
<span>{{student.standard}}</span>
```

Comment: I think your Studentsession is undefined or null... put a console and check the value of Studentsession

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check

```
  var Studentsession = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('student_session'));
  if(Studentsession){
    this.student.StudRollNo = Studentsession[0].StudRollNo;
    this.student.StudName = Studentsession[0].StudName;
    this.student.Standard = Studentsession[0].Standard;
  }
```

Comment: Im having value in `console.log(Studentsession[0].StudRollNo);` but its not assing while `this.student.StudRollNo = Studentsession[0].StudRollNo;`

Comment: you need to instantiate student object do this before all 3 lines this.student = {};

Comment: **Error Build:Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IStudent'** this error occured after I added `this.student = {};`

Comment: no bro its not working. I'm getting following errors. **Build:Unused label** and **Build:'IDashboard' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here**

Comment: can you create a plunker or stackblitz

Comment: both sites are blocked in our company.Codes which are in question is my complete code. other than that I dont have anyother code for this.

Comment: somehow I overcome with that previous errors. But i'm getting another one kindly check my code. I had updated it